# how to subset a data frame by two conditions in another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data frames.

```
ID            Date
 1      1999-01-01
 1      2000-01-01
 1      2001-01-01
 2      1999-01-01
 2      2000-01-01
 3      1998-01-01
 3      1999-01-01
 4      2000-01-01
```

and

```
ID            Date
 1      1999-03-01
 2      2000-01-01
 3      1998-01-01
```

My goal is to subset the first data frame by ID in the second data frame. Then in each subgroup of ID, I only select the Date that is no earlier than the Date in the second data frame. For example, I only select the second and third row of ID 1 because their Dates are not earlier than 1999-03-01 in the second data frame. My desired outcome is

```
ID            Date
 1      2000-01-01
 1      2001-01-01
 2      2000-01-01
 3      1998-01-01
 3      1999-01-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `dplyr` package by joining the second data frame onto the first and using a filter. If the columns have the same name, `dplyr` will add .x and .y onto the column names, so your code would look something like this.

```
 df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>% filter(Date.x >= Date.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data frames are data tables you can use the code below to join the two tables on matching `ID`s and `Date` of `df1` >= `Date` of `df2`, which will return the result directly without requiring an extra filter step.

```
library(data.table)

df1[df2, on = .(ID, Date >= Date), .(ID, Date = x.Date)]

#    ID       Date
# 1:  1 2000-01-01
# 2:  1 2001-01-01
# 3:  2 2000-01-01
# 4:  3 1998-01-01
# 5:  3 1999-01-01
```

Data used

```
df1 <- fread('
ID            Date
 1      1999-01-01
 1      2000-01-01
 1      2001-01-01
 2      1999-01-01
 2      2000-01-01
 3      1998-01-01
 3      1999-01-01
 4      2000-01-01
')
df1[, Date := as.Date(Date)]

df2 <- fread('
ID            Date
 1      1999-03-01
 2      2000-01-01
 3      1998-01-01
')
df2[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
```